# Outputting HTML In Twig From Database

Tags: php, html, twig, slim

I have a database that stores some text as well as some HTML inside of a varchar column. It looks something like this:

```
Click here to go to the site: <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>.
```

However when I output this to the HTML page it appears as plain text and is not a clickable link.

**How do I make it output as a valid HTML tag and create a clickable href?**

I fetch the data using a Slim route:

```
$app->get('/projects/:id', function($id) use ($app) {
    // Open Dataabse Connection
    $con = connect_db();
    // Query for all Projects with specific Id
    $project = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE projectId=".$id."")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    // Get Documents associated with Project Id
    $documents = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ProjectDocuments WHERE projectId=".$id."")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    // Get Student Updates by Project Id
    $updates = $con->query("SELECT * FROM StudentUpdates LEFT JOIN ASAPers ON ASAPers.userId = StudentUpdates.userId 
        WHERE projectId=".$id." ORDER BY StudentUpdates.date DESC LIMIT 5")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $projectArray = array();

    foreach ($project as $key => $value) {
        $project->{$key} = htmlspecialchars_decode($value);
        array_push($projectArray, $project->{$key});
    }

    print_r($projectArray);

    // Render Single Project page
    $app->render('single.project.twig', array('project'=>$projectArray, 'updates'=>$updates, 'documents'=>$documents));
});
```

Inside single.project.twig

```
<h2>{{ project[1] }}</h2>
<p>{{ project[2] }}</p>
```

**If I print the array out in PHP it appears as a HTML link! However, as soon as I print out my variable using Twig it appears as plain text again!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this out. For anybody who sees this here is the answer.

```
<h2>{{ project[1] | raw }}</h2>
<p>{{ project[2] | raw }}</p>
```

Adding `| raw` will output the HTML as HTML.